# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when using type() function

Tags: python

I keep getting this error.  My code is:

```
decimal_number = 344

a = bin(decimal_number)

print (a)
print (type(a))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not see any error in this code.

Comment: Refer to https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable/  It might be possible that the error is in some other section of your code.

Comment: Check your previous code, you assigned the `type` function to a string somewhere else. Look for something like this: `type = 'oopsy'`.

Comment: it works great for me
`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> decimal_number = 344
>>> a = bin(decimal_number)
>>> print (a)
0b101011000
>>> print (type(a))
<class 'str'>`